# After installing Visual Studio SP1, LC.exe can't be found by the build. Solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, vsx, visual-studio-2008-sp1

After installing VS Sp1, the build breaks as it can't find LC.exe (to run on top of license files). Seems like SP1 don't install LC.exe

I found in this MSDN forum post and the solution I found is, I should install Windows SDK.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/93fe03a0-117c-406e-b0ea-c2e2227e1835/

Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5 is over 1.3Gb of download, and I don't want to download and install that for solving such a simple issue. Argggg... Any other quick fixes for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read in some forum (sorry, can't remember which) that it was enough to remove the file licenses.licx; I did and the problem stopped. I didn't try to find out why the file had got added in the first place (my project was built without trouble before). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue some time ago, the only way that worked for me was uninstalling VS 2008 and reinstalling again together with the service packs.

Comment: That's a very painful solution. Looking forward for something like downloading LC.exe from some where and then modifying the registry keys